# Execute query in Mongoose schema validation

Tags: node.js, mongodb, validation, mongoose, mongoose-schema

Im trying to setup my MongoDB design in such a way that there is a `projects` collection, and a `people` collection. The `Project` model schema contains a `_people` item, which references the `People` model. (As opposed to the People model having a field to reference the project he/she belongs to. It needs to be like this)

I need to run a validation whenever a new document is created in the `people` container, that there can be only one manager per a project. This would be very easy if it was possible for me to execute a query for the elements validation in the schema, but I don't believe thats possible...

Heres the schema for the `People` model currently:

```js
const peopleSchema = new Schema( {
    name: {
        type: Schema.Types.String,
        required: true,
        minlength: 3,
        maxlength: 25,
        trim: true,
        select: true
    },
    isManager: {
        type: Schema.Types.Boolean,
        default: false,
        validate: {
            validator: function ( v ) {
                // How can I check if there are any existing `people` documents with the 
                // `isManager` set to true, which are referenced by the same project.
                // If I can return a promise from here, then I can just execute a query and verify the results
            },
            message: 'There can be only one manager per each group'
        }
    }
})
```

As you can see in the `isManager.validate.validator` function, I noted that if this documents `isManager` is set to true, I need to find a way to check that there isn't already a `person` document referenced by the same project that is also a manager.

Knowing which project is referencing this document isn't an issue, I will have that somewhere, I just need to know how to run a query.. is that possible?

Answer (score 2):

I was able to accomplish the desired effect by using Mongooses [Middleware](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/middleware.html) functionality. Setting up the validation inside the [pre-save hook](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model-save) worked just fine

Comment: How did you do that? My query just hangs inside the hook's scope while working fine outside...